# Current user in class

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc

I want to get the current user and fill it in the currentuser at the moment I make a new article just like when I make a new date at the moment I make the article.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity;

namespace CeeLearnAndDo.Models
{
    public class Article
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string CurentUser { get; set; }
        public string Title { get; set; }
        public DateTime CreationDate { get; set; }
        public string Content { get; set; }
        public Article()
        {
            CreationDate = DateTime.Now;
            CurentUser = 
        }
    }
}
```

If you need anymore info just ask me.

Comment: Assuming you have actually got the login/authorize code in your ASP.NET project, check out `IPrincipal`.

Comment: I do have that but how does IPrincipal work?

Comment: User.Identity.Name

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
CurentUser = User.Identity.Name;
```

Comment: @Robin in your code it will be `var article = new Article { CurrentUser = User.Identity.Name }` or `var article = new Article(User.Identity.Name)`. You cannot assign it within the class like you are doing with _CreationDate_ because _Article_ does not know about the User object.